# How can I login to Ubuntu via ssh and automatically sudo su?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

From my Mac Terminal I can login via ssh to my various Ubuntu servers without entering a password. That's fine. But the work I do in Ubuntu requires me to have root access, so immediately after login I always execute `sudo su`which is an extra step and requires manually entering my password at that point.

What's a good way to avoid that extra step so I login with my user name as I do now, but immediately have the `sudo su` executed for me (or anything with an equivalent result)?

Thanks.

Comment: Many professional clients (ie. [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) etc. allow you to provide 'on connect' scripts which are just executed after successful logins. You could put both lines in there and it would work fine. You should keep in mind that your current approach is a sign of weak security, as in practice a hacker is only a single username/password combo away from full unrestricted root access. On a public server you should not use `sudo` lightly, and prefer introducing multiple security layers, like at least a different root password to escalate to high privileges.

Comment: Dude sorry to say, but if this is the level of experience with linux... DO NOT automatically login as root every time. Especially when it is for your work! There will be a day that you will do something stupid and with root permissions you can break your server towards a point of no return.... believe me I know! I have 15 years linux experience and for work related stuff,.. I only use sudo when I need to.. I do not want to be responsible (again) for wiping out loads of data or causing downtime. You have been warned!

Comment: I log in as root all the time, and I've never had any p☀

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do seems very insecure; essentially you are providing root privs to anyone who logs in as you. However, it can be done.

On the Ubuntu machine that you are ssh'ing into:

1. Grant yourself passwordless sudo permissions. You can do this for all commands, or you can be a little more secure and define a specific command. First, launch the sudo configuration editor:

   $ sudo visudo

Then define what user you want to be able to run the `su` command without a password. I'll assume your username is `doug` (based on your stackoverflow handle), and that the server hostname is `ubuntubox`:

```
doug ubuntubox = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su
```

Now you should be able to execute this command without a password:

```
sudo su
```

2. In order for that command to occur immediately upon login, add the command to the very top of your ~/.bash_profile. If you have no such file, create one:

   `$ touch ~/.bash_profile
   $ echo "sudo su -" > ~/.bash_profile`
3. Log out of your ubuntu server, because bash_profile only gets sourced upon login.
4. Log into your server. As soon as your shell opens, it should sudo su you into a root shell.

If ~/.bash_profile isn't getting sourced at login:

```
$ echo ". $HOME/.bash_profile" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Step 1 works fine. However steps 2-4 don't seem to work. The `sudo su -` doesn't get automatically sourced. I also tried putting it in my .bashrc as lserni suggested below, but it doesn't get sourced. However, I am able to save a step so far in not entering my password.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible solution. You may need to source .bash_profile explicitly in .bashrc

Comment: Did you mean to use the `>` redirect operator in your edit rather than the `>>` operator? The redirect operator would just replace the current contents of .bashrc with the contents of .bash_profile, and I would lose what is in .bashrc, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, I apologise! I hope you caught that BEFORE doing it. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I caught it afterwards, but I had a backup. It's still not working, but it may be because of the shell I'm using (sh it seems). Still checking. Thanks.

Comment: also try 'source $HOME/.bash_profile' in .bashrc instead of '. $HOME/.blah'  - the dot is shorthand, i guess it would be better to spell it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101161/discussion-between-klaatu-von-schlacker-and-doug-lerner).

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: if you're doing this, at least disable password login for SSH, and use keys instead. Otherwise, as others have already observed, your system is a single password away from being wide open. With keys, at least the attacker needs to filch your identity key first.

Securing SSH: in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, set the lines

```
PermitRootLogin         no
RSAAuthentication       yes
PubkeyAuthentication    yes
PasswordAuthentication  no
```

To automatically run sudo, you can put the command in your `.loginrc` or `.bashrc` file (or `.profile` if you're running other shells; Ubuntu also has dash in addition to bash. See [this article](https://vishnupalakkal.wordpress.com/2014/07/14/about-default-shell-in-ubuntu-sh-dash-bash-and-startup-files/)).

```
# This is my .bashrc. There are many like it, but this is mine.

# You can also set some variables if you ever need them.
#export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
#export SVN_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
#export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim

sudo su
```

Then to **also** remove the password from `su`, you need to run `visudo` on each server and add, say,

```
Cmnd_Alias  INSECURE_ROOTSHELL   = /bin/su

ubuntu      ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: INSECURE_ROOTSHELL
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already using keys to login. So I don't use a password to login from this particular computer.

Comment: I see your bashrc isn't working. I'm not sure now, but I *think* it must be owned by the user, and mode 640 (chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.bashrc; chmod 640 /home/ubuntu/.bashrc) for security reasons.

Comment: Hi. I think the problem is that I must not be running bash. If I do an `echo $0` the result is just plain old `sh`.

Comment: Updated answer adding .profile reference.